# Finding pairs in an array that are equal to an input value

Tags: c

I have to find out if there is any pair of i,j such that `array[i]^2 + array[j]^2 == x^2`
.
If there are such pairs, I need to print all such `(i,j)`. Otherwise, print “There are no such pairs”.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

 int size=10, i, x,j;

 int Array[size];
 printf("What is the value of x:");
 scanf("%d",&x);

 for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    printf("Enter array value :");
    scanf("%d",&Array[i]);
 }
 for(i=0;i<size;){
    for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
        if((Array[i]*Array[i])+(Array[j]*Array[j])==x*x)  //how do I complete this for loop?

 }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java ... please don't include irrelevant tags.

Comment: You need to keep a counter of the number of (i, j) pairs that satisfy the condition, and you need to print out the values that do satisfy the condition.  After the end of the loop, check the counter; if the answer is zero, print the appropriate message.

Comment: you missed i++ in the second for

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo're almost there, why weren't you incrementing the value of `i`? Keep a `counter` to count the matched pairs, then print those or if nothing is found print whatever you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int size = 10, i, x, j;

    int Array[size];
    printf("What is the value of x:");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter array value :");
        scanf("%d", &Array[i]);
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if ((Array[i] * Array[i]) + (Array[j] * Array[j]) == x * x) {
                printf("%d %d\n", Array[i], Array[j]);
                counter++;
            }
    }
    if (!counter) {
        printf("There are no such pairs\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```